# Change the word "Appendices" in TOC to "Bijlagen"

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am trying to change the name of the "Appendices" part in my Table of contents to the dutch word "Bijlagen".

So far I have this, but the word "Appendices" still appears in my table of contents:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Bijlage}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Bijlagen}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhoudsopgave}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Eerste hoofdstuk}
\chapter{Tweede hoofdstuk}

\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{Eerste bijlage}
Text eerste bijlage.
\chapter{Tweede bijlage}
Text van tweede bijlage.
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You need to modify the macro `\appendixtocname` as well. E.g., `\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Bijlagen}`. (See also page 3 of the user guide of the `appendices` package.)